# Cin read number and check for integer

Tags: c++, numbers, integer

Hy,

I want to read a number in c++ with the cin function. I know there are a lot of threads but I didn't found a perfekt solution.

First I tried it with **cin.fail()** function. But if I input a number like this **12asdf** it reads the **12** correct and didn't throw an error.

Then I tried to read a string and convert it with the **atoi()** function but if I read a string like this **12asdf** I have the same problem. It reads the 12 correct and throws no error.

The I tried it with the function but the all_of function isn't available in visual 2013.

```
if ( std::all_of(input.begin(), input.end(), std::isdigit) )
{
     //input is integer
}
```

How can I check an input like this **12asdf** and throw an error?

Best regards

Comment: IIRC, `boost::lexical_cast` checks the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
  return !s.empty() && std::find_if(s.begin(),
    s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}
```

and then use it like below:

```
  std::string num;
  std::cout << "Enter number: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, num);
  while (!is_number(num)) {
    std::cout << "Input is not a number , enter again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    num.clear();
    std::getline(std::cin, num);
  }
```

Comment: Calling [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) with a negative argument will cause undefined behavior (unless that value happens to be `EOF`). Therefore, `std::isdigit(c)` should be changed to `std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007070/12149471) to another question for the reason behind this.