# isdigit(c) - a char or int type?

Tags: c++

I have written the following code to test if the given input is a digit or not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char c;

    cout<<"Please enter a digit: ";
    cin>>c;

    if(isdigit(c)) //int isdigit(int c) or char isdigit(char c)
    {
        cout<<"You entered a digit"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"You entered a non-digit value"<<endl;
    }
}
```

My question is: what should be the input variable type? char or int?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391765/correct-way-of-using-isdigit-function-in-c (disclaimer I answered that)

Comment: yes i did read that answer. but my book has given it as character handeling function. so if its an int type, why its used or named as character handeling function?

Comment: plus am new to c++, so i do apologize if my question is too basic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way of using isDigit() function in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391765/correct-way-of-using-isdigit-function-in-c)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The situation is unfortunately a bit more complex than has been told by the other answers.

First of all: the first part of your code is correct (disregarding multiple-byte encodings); if you want to read a single `char` with `cin`, you'll have to use a `char` variable with `>>` operator.

Now, about `isdigit`: why does it take an `int` instead of a `char`?

It all comes from C; `isdigit` and its companion were born to be used along with functions like `getchar()`, which read a character from the stream and return an `int`. This in turn was done to provide the character *and* an error code: `getchar()` can return `EOF` (which is defined as some implementation-defined negative constant) through its return code to signify that the input stream has ended.

So, the basic idea is: negative = error code; positive = actual character code.

Unfortunately, this poses interoperability problems with "regular" `char`s.

Short digression: `char` ultimately is just an integral type with a very small range, but a particularly stupid one. In most occasions - when working with bytes or character codes - you'd want it to be `unsigned` by default; OTOH, for coherency reasons with other integral types (`int`, `short`, `long`, ...), you may say that the right thing would be that plain `char` should be `signed`. The Standard chose the most stupid way: plain `char` is either `signed` or `unsigned`, depending from whatever the implementor of the compiler decides<sup>1</sup>.

So, you have to be prepared for `char` being either `signed` or `unsigned`; in most implementations it's `signed` by default, which poses a problem with the `getchar()` arrangement above.

If `char` is used to read bytes and is `signed` it means that all bytes with the high bit set (AKA bytes that, read with an `unsigned` 8-bit type would be >127) turn out to be negative values. This obviously isn't compatible with the `getchar()` using negative values for `EOF` - there could be overlap between actual "negative" characters and `EOF`.

So, when C functions talk about receiving/providing characters into `int` variables the contract is always that the character is assumed to be a `char` that has been cast to an `unsigned char` (so that it is always positive, negative values overflowing into the top half of its range) and then put into an `int`. Which brings us back to the `isdigit` function, which, along its companion functions, has this contract as well:

> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

(C99, §7.4, ¶1)

So, long story short: your `if` should be at the very least:

```
if(isdigit((unsigned char)c))
```

The problem is not just a theoretical one: several widespread C library implementations use the provided value straight as an index into a lookup table, so negative values will read into unallocated memory and segfault your program.

Also, you are not taking into account the fact that the stream may be closed, and thus `>>` returning without touching your variable (which will be at an uninitialized value); to take this into account, you should check if the stream is still in a valid state before working on `c`.

---

1. Of course this is a bit of an unfair rant; as *@Pete Becker* noted in the comment below, it's not like they were all morons, but just that the standard mostly tried to be compatible with existing implementations, which were probably evenly split between unsigned and signed `char`. Traces of this split can be found in most modern compilers, which can generally change the signedness of `char` through command line options (`-fsigned-char`/`-funsigned-char` for gcc/clang, `/J` in VC++).

Comment: The standard makes `char` either signed or unsigned because that's what different compilers did at the time that C was standardized. Backward compatibility is important, and should not be casually dismissed as "stupid". That aside, good answer!

Answer (score -2):

If you want to read a single character and check whether it is a digit or not then it should be char.

If you set it as int then multiple characters will be read and the result of isDigit will always be true.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first sentence is wrong for the reasons stated in the other answer. The second sentence is also wrong, as multiple characters will not necessarily be read and it will not always make `isdigit` true.