# How can this statement be simplified?

Tags: c++, if-statement, simplify

I'm learning c++, and have had some moderate experience in other languages and I am transferring a lot of knowledge but not all knowledge is transferable.

My IDE has told me that this statement can be simplified but I don't see how?

```
if (answer[0] == 'y'||answer[0] == 'Y')
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: More context is probably needed to find the solution. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: try `if ((answer[0] | 0x20) == 'Y')`

Comment: @kichik That seems to make some assumptions on encoding...

Comment: Is this the only "if" or is there a more complicated logical tree? E.g. is there an "else"? Or is this within an outer "if"?

Comment: It is _possible_ that `return (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'Y');` would suffice.

Comment: @DavidBowling Supposed there is a `else return false;` only.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
if (std::tolower(answer[0]) == 'y')
    return true;
```

That's also how you should get input from the user when the case doesn't matter, instead of hardcoding cases.

Note: In theory, you need to make sure that `answer[0]` is in a valid range, or else you'll get undefined behavior (for non-ASCII characters and another `std::locale` for example). Your `std::locale` also matters in theory, but that's rarely the case if you are only dealing with ASCII characters.

Comment: so how will he check _if answer[0] is in a valid range_ **wouldn't it add another check to validate the range?**

Comment: @ItbanSaeed In theory yes, but not in practice. Characters *very* rarely exceed the range of an `unsigned char`.

Comment: Is there any performance improve with `std::tolower` or it just a choice of syntax?

Comment: @ChunMingSHIU I very much doubt it. I would recommend my version because it's less duplication, but yeah, it's basically your choice.

Comment: Usual reminder: you cannot pass a `char` straight to `tolower`, you *have* to cast it to `unsigned char`, otherwise you risk undefined behavior. Your program *will* crash with at least one widely used C runtime library. That's a -1 until you fix this answer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia But if I pass for example a `1`, do I still have to cast? I thought that if you could guarantee that the value is within the range of an `unsigned char`, you're safe?

Comment: 1 is fine, the problem arises when you get negative `char`s. See here for a complete explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007070/214671

Comment: I very much doubt this is what OP's IDE had in mind.

Comment: @Chris True, but it is still a valid answer to "How can this statement be simplified". With just the snippet the OP posted, it is impossible to know.