# C program that goes through a string and flags for non-letters

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C program that goes through a string of characters, and prints out "NON-LETTER" if the given argument through the command line.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if (!isalpha(argv[i])){
            printf("NON-LETTER\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting a segmentation fault. 
Is this because of the comparison I'm making with `isalpha()`? It looks like `argv[i]` is a string?

Comment: [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) expects an `int`, not a `char*`

Comment: In which case, the code shown should not even compile, let alone crash.

Comment: also argv is a char ** not  char *  .... are you doing this for all the commandline parameters?

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's not how C works :-) int can easily be recast as a * and vice-versa

Comment: @AhmedMasud aaah sorry I misinterpreted your comment, I thought you meant that the `main` signature was wrong. I'll delete my comment immediately.

Comment: @MatteoItalia :-) ah okay I see how my comment is a bit badly worded

Answer (score 2):

`argv[i]` is a `char *` pointing to the i-th argument (a string), while [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) expects a single character expressed as an `int`<sup>1</sup>.

What happens here is that you are passing a pointer, it gets implicitly converted to `int`, `isalpha` tries to interpret it as a character (probably as an index in a lookup table) and everything explodes (technically, it's undefined behavior).

What you probably wanted to do was to check each argument character by character, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; argv[i][j] != '\0'; ++j) {
            if (!isalpha((unsigned char)argv[i][j])) {
                printf("NON-LETTER\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

1. in particular, the `char` value casted to `unsigned char` casted to `int`, [due to unfortunate reasons I detailed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003739/isdigitc-a-char-or-int-type/45007070#45007070).

Comment: you have a bad dereference in the expression `isalpha((unsigned char)argv[i][j])`

Comment: @AhmedMasud: thank you, fixed. It was a remaining of a previous version where I straight used a pointer to iterate over the string, which I subsequently changed to indexing to ease it up for beginners.

Comment: You have a very kind way of commenting and answering, and I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) expects int, and your input argv[i] is char *. Depend on your code, you can judge letter or not according to [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

    if (!(argv[i][0] >= 'a' && argv[i][0] <= 'z')) {
      printf("NON-LETTER\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is in this part of the code:

```
        if (!isalpha(argv[i])){
            printf("NON-LETTER\n");
        }
```

argv is a pointer to a pointer. (Think of it as an array of strings, and each string is an array of characters)

So, you need two loops, one that runs through the array of strings `argv[k]` and then another that looks at the k<sup>th</sup> string.

There is a hidden hint, only look at it if you have trouble:

### Hint 1:

> for (k = 1; k < argc; k++ ) {
>           for ( j = 0; argv[k][j] != 0; j++ ) {
>              if( !isalpha((unsigned char) argv[k][j]) {
>                     // do something here
>              }
>        }
>
>   The `(unsigned char)` casting is necessary because of how argv[] (declared as a char) may be interpreted as a signed value, and when it  gets recast to int (which will have a signed bit without the cast) will be misinterpreted by the checking function.
>  it's explained further in the isalpha man page.