# strlen() warning concerning conversion between pointers | C99 | CLion

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, implicit-conversion, strlen

C99 | CLion 2020.3.1

While using the strlen() function, CLion showed the warning

```
"Passing 'unsigned char [20]' to parameter of type 'const char *' converts between pointers to 
integer types with different sign"
```

The program compiles and executes as desired, though.

Relevant code:

```c
unsigned char arr[20] = "foo";
unsigned int len = strlen(arr);
```

If someone could please help me understand the warning and has a ***good*** way to fix it, that would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Strings shouldn't be `unsigned`.  Change the type to `char arr[20]`.

Comment: This causes a later error when the arr is passed into the toupper() function: "Clang-Tidy: Narrowing conversion from 'int' to signed type 'char' is implementation-defined"

Comment: That's a truly unfortunate restriction of `toupper()`.  I'm not sure what the recommend fix for it is these days, but it's *not* to make all your strings be @no_one `unsigned char`!  I recommend making the `toupper` issue an explicit part of the question -- or perhaps ask a second question about it.  Or perhaps I will -- I've been wondering about this, too.  (You could use an explicit cast in every `toupper` call, but that's obviously an extreme nuisance, too.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I believe it's a throwback to K&R when everything was an `int`.

Comment: Oh, I know the history, I'm just wondering what programmers are expected to do about it these days, in the face of chars that are still signed by default, and "helpful" compiler warnings like the one the OP mentioned.

Comment: @no_one : clang-tidy warnings are not errors. It does not make this correction wrong (which is because `char` being either `signed` or `unsigned` is implementation defined).  Passing `arr` to `toupper()` was always wrong in any case.  `toupper()` is not a string function.  It would not cause the warning you suggest.  SO comments are not the place to discuss run-on questions.  It is assigning the return to `toupper()` to a `char` that causes the narrowing, not the type of `arr`.  Post a new question if you must, but the answer is to use an explicit cast to tell clang-tidy you did it on purpose.

Comment: With respect to my earlier comment about having to cast the argument passed to `toupper()`, there's some more information at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003739/isdigitc-a-char-or-int-type).

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the warning is that the function `strlen` expects a pointer of the type `char *` while you are using an argument expression of the type `unsigned char *` and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

Just use explicit casting to the type `char *`

```
size_t len = strlen( ( char * )arr);
```

Otherwise change the element type of the array from the type `unsigned char` to the type `char`.

It is better to declare the variable `len` as having the type `size_t` because it is the type of the returned value of the function `strlen`.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion (in C, but not C++) - this appears to be a static analysis warning from CLion rather than a compiler error.

Comment: @Clifford There is no implicit conversion from the type unsigned char * to the type char *. It is only the type void * can be implicitly converted to or from other pointer type.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/SkzItWUl_ - if it compiles, it cast it - implicitly.  I am not saying it is safe or not implementation defined behaviour, but it is implicit.  Interestingly though the warning `warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]` is issued for both `unsigned char` and `signed char` - only `char` silences the warning.  Of course my test is with gcc not clang.

Comment: @Clifford It is a defect of the compiler.

Comment: Probably.  gcc seems to treat `char` as a separate and "more qualified" type than `unsigned char` or `signed char`.  There are in fact three valid implicit conversions - not just to `void*`.  I guess gcc is applying the "_Any pointer to a given type can be implicitly converted into a pointer to a more qualified version of that type—that is, a type with one or more additional type qualifiers._" rule.  But it is not clear that `char*` is somehow more qualified that `unsigned char*`.  Perhaps a permissive thing to prevent breaking existing code.

Comment: Curious - gdbonline reports its `--version` as `gcc (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 6.5.0 20181026`, but the same code on godbolt is correctly rejected by all supported gcc versions as you say (and I agree) it should be. Oh well, not really a discussion for here.