# How do I operate with words read from keyboard without using strtok?

Tags: c++

So, until now I've read the string from keyboard using cin.get or cin.getline and then using a pointer to modifying every word like so:

```
p=strtok(string,' ');
```

but I've learned that I can read word by word such as:

```
char word[101];
cin>>word;
```

I am curious if I can find a stopping condition if I have an unknown number of words
I've tried using:

```
while(cin>>word)
{
   //condition
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char cuv[101],maxim[101]="nu exista",ok; 
int main() 
{
   while(cin>>cuv) { 
        if(cuv[0]<=57 && cuv[0]>=48)
            if(cuv[0]>maxim[0] || ok==0) { 
                ok=1; strcpy(maxim,cuv); 
            }
     }
      cout<<maxim;
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `while(cin>>word)` should be a good start. What is the problem you had when you used that?

Comment: `char word[101];` you should not use this in `c++`. This is very error prone. Instead use `std::string word;`

Comment: @drescherjm it reads endlessly

Comment: and I am using :"using namespace std;"

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char cuv[101],maxim[101]="nu exista",ok;

int main()
{
    while(cin>>cuv)
    {
        if(cuv[0]<=57 && cuv[0]>=48)
            if(cuv[0]>maxim[0] || ok==0)
            {
                ok=1;
                strcpy(maxim,cuv);
            }
        
    }
    cout<<maxim;
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Dr8gos dont put code in the comments, edit the question

Comment: @it is initialized with 0 since is declared globally

Comment: Re: `if(cuv[0]<=57 && cuv[0]>=48)` -- these magic numbers don't convey what the code is supposed to do. As a guess, could this be written as `if (std::isdigit(cuv[0])`?

Comment: The type of `ok` should be `bool`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- the console transmits an EOF to the input stream when you type ^D on Unix systems or ^Z on Windows systems.

Comment: OK so the actual question is "why doesnt this code exit the loop"

Comment: @pm100 yeah....

Comment: becuase you have not done neither of the things I said in my answer. There is no 'break' in the loop so you have to type ctrl-d

Comment: @PeteBecker: On platforms on which `char` is signed, the line `if (std::isdigit(cuv[0])` can invoke undefined behavior, unless the function argument is guaranteed to represent a non-negative value. Therefore, `if (std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(cuv[0]))` would be safer. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007070/12149471) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

to exit that loop you have 2 choices

- detect an end condition
- close the input file

End condition (changed to use string)

```
 string word;

while(cin>>word)
{  
   if (word == "quit") break;
}
```

Close the input file

- On linux or mac type `ctrl-d` at the console
- on windows type `ctrl-z`

Your posted code fails because you did not initialize 'Ok'