# How to pass std::isspace to function taking unary predicate as argument?

Tags: c++

I have the following `trim` function

```
std::string trim(const std::string& str, std::function<bool(int ch)> isCharToTrim)
{
   auto trimmedStart = std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), isCharToTrim);
   if (trimmedStart == str.end())
   {
      return "";
   }
   else
   {
      auto trimmedEnd = std::find_if_not(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), isCharToTrim);
      return std::string(trimmedStart, trimmedEnd.base());
   }
}
```

When I pass `std::isspace` as second argument, it compiles with MSVC.
But I get an error with gcc: `error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'isspace' based on conversion to type 'std::function<bool(int)>'`.

Usage of the function that works on MSVC

```
const auto trimmed = trim(test, std::isspace);
const auto trimmed2 = trim(test, std::not_fn(std::isgraph));
const auto trimmed3 = trim(test, [](int ch) { return ch == ' '; });
```

What changes can I make to get it to compile on gcc? Change the argument type?

https://godbolt.org/z/81cjvrh7E

Comment: Wrap the call in a lambda function. `std::isspace` returns an `int` that might be the reason for the problems.

Comment: You cannot take address of most std functions: -> wrap in lambda. (note also the pitfalls of [`std::isspace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) from the doc)

Comment: there is a `std::isspace` template, but thats not the one OP wants to pick. The duplicate is not the right one.

Comment: BTW you cannot use `std::isspace` (and the other `std::is...` functions) on a `char` sequence; they take an `int` argument whose numeric value is expected to come from an `unsigned char` (IOW, you have to cast your `char` to `unsigned char` before calling `std::isspace`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007070/214671

Answer (score 2):

You should not use function pointers to functions in the standard library unless they are explicitly addressable functions.

You can wrap them in a lambda:

```
const auto trimmed = trim(test, [](auto c) { return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });
```

Note that it is not necessary to convert all callables to `std::function` just to call them or pass them to an algorithm. You can accept any callable by making the function a template:

```
 template <typename C>
 std::string trim(const std::string& str, C isCharToTrim);
```

The error complains about an overload because there is https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace in addition to the function you want to pass. Anyhow, strictly speaking the standard merely specifies what happens when you call `std::isspace(int)`. There needs not actually be a function `int std::isspace(int)`, it could be `int std::isspace(int,int=42)`. There can be other overloads present. For this (and perhaps other) reasons it is generally not allowed to take pointers to standard functions.

Comment: You should probably do `const auto trimmed = trim(test, [](auto c) { return std::isspace((unsigned char)c); });`